# Cannot find module '@jf/consts/env-config.const'

Tags: angular, firebase, environment

I have a project here that I downloaded from Github, I want to modify it but I get the error code when I write the command:

```
$ ng serve
```

Error code:

> ERROR in app/app.module.ts:19:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   '@jf/consts/env-config.const'. 19 import {ENV_CONFIG} from
>   '@jf/consts/env-config.const';

code:

```
import {APP_INITIALIZER, Injector, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {AngularFirePerformanceModule} from '@angular/fire/performance';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ENV_CONFIG} from '@jf/consts/env-config.const';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {LayoutComponent} from './shared/components/layout/layout.component';
import {appInit} from './shared/helpers/app-init';
import {FileUploadModule} from './shared/modules/file-upload/file-upload.module';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';

export function init(injector: Injector) {
  return () => {
    return appInit(injector.get(AngularFirestore));
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, LayoutComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    FileUploadModule.forRoot(),

    /**
     * External
     */
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(ENV_CONFIG.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
    AngularFirePerformanceModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: init,
      deps: [Injector],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I tried to create the `{ENV_CONFIG}` file , I don't know what this file should contain.
Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using same tsconfig file as in the project? If not make sure to use define same path variable in your tsconfig file.

Source tsconfig file: https://github.com/Jaspero/fireshop/blob/1d893923dd2c4016b4510b84dde7dfe60796306b/client/tsconfig.json

[image]

Comment: This is the project I am using, but there is no file named env-config.ts
I created it manually and get new error messages. The requested file does not exist and I don't know what should contain in env-config.ts .

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved I created a new file called: `env-config.ts` And i added this :

```
export const ENV_CONFIG = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    databaseURL: '',
    projectId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    appId: '',
    measurementId: ''
  },
  stripe: {
      token: ''
  }
};
```

This works for me now.

Comment: Sorry just saw your message, I was going to say that copy same file as in the GitHub project but looks like you have already figured it out!